# Embedding interactive Bokeh or Plotly figures in Github-hosted site

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, plotly, bokeh

Does anyone have experience embedding interactive plots in a Github-hosted site? I've read that github won't render interactive plots from Bokeh, Plotly, etc., but then other sites seem to be able to? Ideally, what I would like to do is upload a Jupyter notebook containing these plots, and have them show up on my github blog. For some reason though, they won't render while everything else looks fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GitHub scrubs all user-supplied JavaScript from content that it renders. This means  JavaSript-based browser plotting libraries cannot function at all in pages rendered directly by GitHub.

However, you can point https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ at a GitHub repo, and any statically rendered notebooks in the repo will fully function, including plots. See, e.g. the notebooks in

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/index.ipynb

Another option is to opeb notebooks in GitHub repos in MyBinder, which provides live, actually running notebooks that can be interacted with. E.g.

https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/master?filepath=tutorial%2F00%20-%20Introduction%20and%20Setup.ipynb

Comment: As of Bokeh `0.12.6`, it is now possible to export PNG and SVG directly from
Python code. 

There are some optional dependencies that need to be installed.
You can find more information in the [Exporting Plots section of the User Guide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether [bigreddot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406693/bigreddot)'s answer was meant to apply only to github.com - if you're willing to consider [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) (github.io), simply follow [these detailed instructions](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-plotly-visualization-and-embed-it-on-websites-517c1a78568b) by towardsdatascience.

It seems entirely straightforward to host static HTML & Javascript content on Github Pages, including html exports of plotting libraries like plotly.
You can check their [example](https://elizabethts.github.io/publish-plotly-website/) and convince yourself that the javascript in the HTML body has *not* been scrubbed.